# Can't Select Existing Wireless Network In Loki

Tags: wifi

The wifi selector in the upper right generally shows my list of networks, and when I want to change a network, I click the network I want, a check is placed in the circle beside the network, and the PC attempts to connect to the network.

When I try to access my wifi at work, I am unable to select the network.  I click on "workwifi", but it does not receive a check mark.  I have tried forgetting the network and then reconnecting, but the network is still not selectable.  I click on it but nothing happens.

Any ideas for how to make my computer select the network I want to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from your explanation if it might be the same bug as I have had. For me the problem is resolved by opening the Network Settings via the network indicator, going to the Wireless section and connecting to a network from there.